# Unix Permission: different chmod on folder and its files

Tags: linux, unix, chmod, chown

Say a FOLDER is set to chmod 777 but FILES in the folder is set to chmod 755.
Non-owner user can write files to the FOLDER. Then how about overwriting the already existing files? Can the existing files be overwritten by a non-owner user?

Comment: This question is not about programming. It would be a better fit for http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give everyone read, write, and execute permissions on a directory, everyone can create and remove files, including ones that have been created by other users.

If you want to avoid such a behavior (one of your comments mentioned that), you should create another /tmp or /var/tmp directory: Set the sticky bit:

```
$ chmod +t directory
```

With the sticky bit set, every user can create new files, but is unable to remove files from others.

A fair word of warning here though: I do not recommend to secure your uploads with such a feature. Implement a better access control in your frontend instead.

Comment: how is the `user` defined then? Is that the default username that the server is running as? ie. `apache` ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  While non-owners will **not** be able to open a file for editing and change its contents, they **will** be able to remove any file in the directory and replace it with a new file of the same name.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve such purpose? I want non-users be able to upload new files but not able to manipulate already existing files...